# SELECT and UPDATE expo-sqlite queries don't work on Android

Tags: android, react-native, sqlite, expo, expo-sqlite

I'm making a school note app and I want to do an option to add, edit and delete school subjects. Everything works on IOS, but on Android works only adding.

Here's my code:

```
const editSubject = (oldSubjectName, newSubjectName) => {
        db.transaction(tx => {
            tx.executeSql(
                'UPDATE subjects SET subject_name = ? WHERE subject_name = ?',
                [newSubjectName, oldSubjectName],
                (txObj, resultSet) => {
                    console.log('Przedmiot został zaktualizowany');
                    navigation.goBack(); // Wróć do poprzedniego ekranu
                },
                (txObj, error) => {
                    console.log('Nie udało się zaktualizować przedmiotu:', error);
                }
            );
        });

        loadSubjects(setSubjects);
    };

    const deleteSubject = (oldSubjectName) => {
        db.transaction(tx => {
            tx.executeSql(
                'UPDATE subjects SET is_deleted = 1 WHERE subject_name = ?',
                [oldSubjectName],
                (txObj, resultSet) => {
                    console.log('Przedmiot został usuniety');
                    navigation.goBack(); // Wróć do poprzedniego ekranu
                },
                (txObj, error) => {
                    console.log('Nie udało się usunac przedmiotu:', error);
                }
            );
        });
        
        loadSubjects(setSubjects);
    }

export const loadSubjects = (setSubjects) => {
  db.transaction(tx => {
    tx.executeSql(
      'SELECT * FROM subjects WHERE is_deleted = 0', 
      null,
      (txObj, resultSet) => {
        setSubjects(resultSet.rows._array),
        // const subjects = resultSet.rows._array;
        console.log('Przedmioty zostały odświeżone');
      },
      (txObj, error) => console.log(error)
    );
  });
};
```

I was watching tips on internet but I didn't found nothing.